# How do I overcome this "group 'libvirtd' does not exist" issue in installing juju?

Tags: juju

I'm trying to install juju on local environment. For that I installed Ubuntu Server 12.10 and I followed [this juju Getting Started tutorial](https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/getting-started.html). At the step where I run the following command:

```
sudo usermod -a -G libvirtd <YOUR_USER>
```

The error is reported:

```
usermod : group 'libvirtd' does not exist
```

Does someone have ever had this problem and can help me?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Do you have Libvirt installed? This system group is being created by the package `libvirt-bin` if I recall correctly. The steps just above that command will have you install this...

Comment: No I haven't install libvirt-bin maybe it's the problem.
Edit : It works !

Thanks for you quick answer

Comment: I was reading the guide too quickly for my previous comment. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to run this command. The guide states:

> **pre v0.6 users only** Then you need to add yourself to the libvirtd group:
>
> ```
> sudo usermod -a -G libvirtd <YOUR_USER>
> ```

As Ubuntu 12.10 provides `juju` version 0.6, this does not apply.

---

To explain a bit more on the error you got, the `libvirt-bin` package (the base of Libvirt basically) will create this system user group for you. Because you don't need to install this for 0.6 version of Juju, it's not installed and you'll get the error about the group specified not being a valid existent group. The command is listed for pre-0.6 versions and the guide also lists this package to the lists of packages to install for these older versions.

Answer (score -1):

log in as root using this command su -
than use the command  adduser  libvirtd
after that for checking it try the same cmd with same user name if it already added you than it will show you "The user `your user name' is already a member of`libvirtd'."

Comment: `adduser libvirtd` won't help with a missing group `libvirtd` because `adduser` doesn't create user groups. -1